# cannot create special file /dev/pts/0

Tags: linux, filesystems, terminal, devices

When using midnight commander in console, I cannot "toggle" the window (using <kbd>CTRL-o</kbd>

```
Not an xterm or Linux console;
the panels cannot be toggled
```

however, my `$TERM` is set to `linux`.

After some googling, I have found suggestions that the problem might be in missing files in `/dev/pts`. I have `/dev/pts` mounted dynamically as `devpts` but it's empty. When I try to copy `/dev/pts/0` from another machine, I get an error:

```
cannot create special file /dev/pts/0
Operation not permitted
```

Somewhere I found the suggestion to check `sysctl -a | grep pty`. This gives me:

```
# sysctl -a | grep pty
kernel.pty.max = 4096
kernel.pty.nr = 0
kernel.pty.reserve = 1024
```

On another machine, where `/dev/pts/` works, I get:

```
# sysctl -a | grep pty
kernel.pty.max = 4096
kernel.pty.nr = 8
kernel.pty.reserve = 1024
```

I don't know exactly what that means, but it looks like the problem is this:

```
kernel.pty.nr = 0
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

**Note** : I am not using `udev`. My `/dev/` is static (with static dev files with `/dev/pts` mounted as `devpts`

**CORRECTION**: My /dev/pts is mounted as `devpts` (not as `tmpfs`, as stated in my original question).

#### UPDATE:

```
# ls -ld /dev/pt* /dev/pts/*
ls: cannot access /dev/pts/*: No such file or directory
crw-rw-rwT 1 root root   5, 2 Oct  2 00:57 /dev/ptmx
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      0 Sep 30 17:31 /dev/pts

# grep /dev /proc/mounts
/dev/root / ext2 rw,relatime 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
```

Comment: `kernel.pty.nr` is the number of currently-existing terminals. That's a symptom, not a cause. Please post the output of `ls -ld /dev/pt* /dev/pts/*` and `grep /dev /proc/mounts`. Is this a home-compiled kernel? If so, are you absolutely sure you included the necessary options for ptys?

Comment: @Gilles - I have added the output. My kernel is custom, but I know that it works OK on other machines.

Comment: Can you run *any* program that uses ptys? screen? script? xterm? ssh localhost? If those are working then the slave pty devices should appear in /dev/pts while they are active.

Comment: @Wumpus Q. Wumbley - I can run `dtach` and that works fine. When I run it, a device `/dev/pts/0` is created. But `midnight commander` still gives me the same error as before.

Comment: So you should probably give up the idea that your devpts is the cause of the problem and go back to researching the original error message.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your version of `mc` is compiled with `subshell` feature. You can check this by running:

```
$ mc -V
...
With subshell support as default
...
```

A quick Google search returns the following 2 results:

- [Re: no subshell in mc with screen](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/mc/2004-January/msg00031.html)
- [MC doesn't give a subshell for normal users](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.apps.mc.general/868)

On my laptop, when I hit `ctrl+o`, I can see in the `strace` output that the following command is invoked:

`execve("/usr/lib/mc/cons.saver", ["cons.saver", "/dev/pts/8"], [/* 136 vars */]) = 0`

The terminal from where I invoked `mc` was `/dev/pts/8`. So as the second link mentions, make sure `cons.saver` has access to your terminal device.